# Angularjs - Cannot pass parameter

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Angularjs for my mobile app project. My problem is I can't pass my all my parameters to my own API. My API can't detect any post parameters that my app send to it.

```
$http.post("http://xxxxxxxx/api/verify_login.php", {
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "12345678",
    "secret_key": "123456789"
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(status));
});
```

If using Postman it works.

Comment: This looks it may be cross-domain did you enabled CORS?

Comment: still cant pass the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this :

```
var postData = '{"username":"'+varUsername+'", "password" : "'+varPassword+'", "secret_key" : "'+varSecretyKey+'"}';

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://xxxxxxxx/api/verify_login.php',
    data: postData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function(response) {
        $scope.result = response;
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

This will post data as :

```
username=hisname&password=hispassword&secret_key=hiskey
```

keep in mind that, angularjs will automatically convert your postdata as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data) StackOverflow answer helps solve half the problem. Look at the accepted answer. To paraphase the quote on this post:

> By default, jQuery transmits data using Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded and the familiar foo=bar&baz=moe serialization. AngularJS, however, transmits data using Content-Type: application/json and { "foo": "bar", "baz": "moe" } JSON serialization, which unfortunately some Web server languages—notably PHP—do not unserialize natively.

There is a nice way to get it do this - override the default `transformRequest` - this is show in a nice post by Ben Nadel [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm) - Here's a snippet:

```
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "process.cfm",
    transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
    data: {
        id: 4,
        name: "Kim",
        status: "Best Friend"
    }
});
```

He has a fairly simple implementation - if you find that this doesn't work for you, you can use the a detailed version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406789/http-promise-not-resolving-in-controller) - you can inject this factory in your controller.

```
.factory("transformRequestAsFormPost", function() {
    function transformRequest(data, getHeaders) {
        var headers = getHeaders();
        headers["Content-type"] =
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
        return (serializeData(data));
    }
    return (transformRequest);

    function serializeData(data) {
        if (!angular.isObject(data)) {
            return ((data === null) ? "" : data.toString());
        }
        var buffer = [];
        for (var name in data) {
            if (!data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                continue;
            }
            var value = data[name];
            buffer.push(encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent((value ===
                null) ? "" : value));
        }
        var source = buffer.join("&").replace(/%20/g, "+");
        return (source);
    }
});
```